# Where is the mistake in this apparent paradox concerning the Cauchy integral theorem?

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-integration

Consider the real integration: $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{2\pi}}\dfrac{dx}{1-2\alpha\sin x+\alpha^2}$ given that $\alpha^2<1$.

In order to perform this calculation, I define a function over the complex plane as follows:

$f(z) = \dfrac{r}{1-2\alpha\sin \theta+\alpha^2} $ ; $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi), $ $r \in R^{+} \cup \{0\} $.

Now, $1-2\alpha\sin \theta+\alpha^2 = 2\alpha\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg(\alpha+\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\bigg)-\sin \theta\bigg)$. Since $\alpha^2<1$, $\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg| \alpha+\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\bigg|>1$. Therefore, $1-2\alpha\sin \theta+\alpha^2$ can never be zero. This is also equivalent to saying that the denominator of the original integrand as well never goes to zero.

**Approach 1**

I take the contour integration of the function $f(z)$ over the closed path $|z|=1$. Since $1-2\alpha\sin \theta+\alpha^2$ can never be equal to zero, the function $f(z)$ is clearly analytic in the $z$-plane. Therefore, its integration over the closed contour $|z|=1$ will be zero according to the Cauchy integral theorem. But clearly, the contour integration of $f(z)$ over $|z|=1$ is equal to $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{2\pi}}\dfrac{dx}{1-2\alpha\sin x+\alpha^2}$.

Therefore, 
$\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{2\pi}}\dfrac{dx}{1-2\alpha\sin x+\alpha^2} = 0$

**Approach 2**

Since the denominator of the original real integrand can never be zero, it remains either positive or negative everywhere. Therefore, the definite integration over the proposed limits must be non-zero.

Comment: I do not get how you define $f(z)$ in terms of $z$ only. I would say that by setting $z=e^{i\theta}$ (no $r$ involved) we have that $$\frac{r}{1-2\alpha\sin\theta+\alpha^2} = \frac{r}{1+i\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)+\alpha^2}$$ that is a meromorphic function.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how you define $f(z)$ in terms of $z$ only". But I don't think that setting $z=e^{i\theta}$ should help in finding appropriate poles to be used for applying the Cauchy theorem because the poles that I need to find for the application of the Cauchy theorem are the ones that lie in the interior of the contour of integration. Setting $z=e^{i\theta}$ would restrict me from finding what goes in the interior the contour.

Comment: If you write $$f(z) = \frac{r}{1-2\alpha\sin\theta+\alpha^2}$$ you are defining a constant function, since the LHS depends on $z$ but the RHS does not.

Comment: If you set $z=r e^{i\theta}$ then $\theta=-i\log\frac{z}{r}$ and $$f(z) = \frac{r}{1-2\alpha\sin\left(-i\log\frac{z}{r}\right)+\alpha^2}$$ is clearly not a holomorphic function, but a meromorphic one.

Comment: (This is my response to your comment regarding I am defining a constant function.) No. As I have mentioned, $z=re^{i\theta}$. You can write $f(z)$ as $\dfrac{|z|}{1-2\alpha \bigg(\dfrac{z-\dfrac{1}{z}}{2|z|i}\bigg)+\alpha^2}$ if you wish. I am writing it the way I have written in the question for the sake of simplicity and to make it manifest that $|z|$ is a non-negative real number and that $\bigg(\dfrac{z-\dfrac{1}{z}}{2|z|i}\bigg)$ ranges from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: Long story short, the "*is clearly analytic*" part is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no paradox. We have $\sin \theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$, hence by setting $e^{i\theta}=z$

$$\frac{1}{\alpha^2-2\alpha\sin\theta+1} = \frac{1}{\alpha^2+\alpha i\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)+1}=\frac{1}{\alpha+iz}\cdot\frac{1}{\alpha-\frac{i}{z}}$$
we get a meromorphic function of the $z$ variable. In particular

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\alpha^2-2\alpha\sin\theta+1}=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{-i\,dz}{(\alpha+i z)\left(\alpha z-i\right)} $$
is the integral over the unit circle of a function with a pole at $z=\frac{i}{\alpha}$ and a pole at $z=i\alpha$.
Since $\alpha^2<1$ only the pole at $z=i\alpha$ lies inside the integration contour and

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\alpha^2-2\alpha\sin\theta+1} = 2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(\frac{-i\,dz}{(\alpha+i z)\left(\alpha z-i\right)},z=i\alpha\right)$$
by the residue theorem. I guess you can take it from here (and get $\frac{2\pi}{1-\alpha^2}$ as the actual value of the integral).

Comment: Ok. The only thing I don't understand is this: Your $z$ is not allowed to take any value for which $|z| \neq 1$ because you have defined that $z=e^{i \theta}$. So, the poles found are not actual poles of the function where $z$ is not a generic variable but is a constrained one. If you take a generic $z$ then the expression whose poles you should find is $f(z) = \dfrac{|z|}{1-2\alpha \bigg(\dfrac{z-\dfrac{1}{z}}{2|z|i}\bigg)+\alpha^2}$. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: That is not a meromorphic or holomorphic function of the $z$ variable, so it is useless. I used $z=e^{i\theta}$ (not involving any extra radius) because in such a case $\sin\theta = \frac{z-1/z}{2i}$, simply. And with such substitution it is clear how the real integral over the $[0,2\pi)$ range becomes an integral over the unit circle in the complex plane.

Comment: Once you get $$\oint_{|z|=1} g(z)\,dz = \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{-i}{(\alpha+iz)(\alpha z-i)}\,dz $$ you may forget anything about the initial function. Now you have a meromorphic function, integrated along the unit circle. Use the residue theorem and win.

Comment: @Dvij: how much time are you studying Complex Analysis from? Which book are you using?

Comment: Ok, I get it. I have made peace with it by assuming that somehow you got the function $g(z)$ (for which you used some educated guesswork of working it out backward from the given integration) and since the integration of $g(z)$ over some contour is equal to the exact integration that needs to be found, I can call it equal to the sum of the residues of $g(z)$.

Comment: I am using Schaum's outline. Any comments or suggestions?

Comment: But I still don't understand what is wrong in my argument (presented in the question) to show that the function $ \dfrac{r}{1-2\alpha\sin \theta+\alpha^2}$ is analytic. I think I have clearly shown that the denominator never gets zero. I haven't applied the actual checks for the analyticity but I guess it shouldn't be an issue as the functions look pretty well-behaved.

Comment: @Dvij: well-behaved is not enough to ensure analyticity in the complex plane. $f(z)=\frac{|z|^2+1}{z^4+z^2+1}$ is well-behaved, but it is not holomorphic or meromorphic. The Cauchy-Riemann equation equips the space of holomorphic function with a great rigidity: it is enough to think that any differentiable function in the complex sense is indeed analytic. Anyway, Schaum's fine, this kind of manipulations only require a bit of practice.